# UITextView vertical text alignment when entering newline

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm having a bad time when vertically centering a `UITextView` text. When I press `Enter` or when the text doesn't fit in a single line and goes to the next line, the text doesn't stay vertically aligned until I hit another key.

Here are the images:
This one is working, [image: working fine]

This one is bugged, [image: bug]

This one is working again, [image: working again]

Here is my code running:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        messageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = messageTextView.contentSize.height
        sendBarHeightConstraint.constant = messageTextView.contentSize.height + 11
        secondBarHeightConstraint.constant = messageTextView.contentSize.height
        alignTextVerticalInTextView(messageTextField)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func alignTextVerticalInTextView(textView :UITextView) {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(textView.bounds), CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    var topoffset = (textView.bounds.size.height - size.height * textView.zoomScale) / 2.0
    topoffset = topoffset < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topoffset
    textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -topoffset)
}
```

I can't seem to find any fix for the new line key which seems to reset the behaviour of the `UITextView` text until I hit a key.

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I solved my problem !

Comment: What is the type of the component?! you are mentioning in the question that it is a UITextField, but in your code snippet you are handling UITextViewDelegate methods

Comment: Whoops, the big mistake I did. Thank you very much for pointing it out !

Comment: so is it a UITextField?

Comment: This is a UITextView but I changed the variable name since its name was confusing, sorry.

Comment: what if you changed it to UITextField? does it solve the problem?

Comment: UITextField is a 1 line only component. I need to handle more than 1 line.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?